# How to change view component by link click?

Tags: angular

I have an registration form(Component). In this form there is link recovery password.

How to change view in this form by clicking link  with changin URL address to `/registration/recovery` ?

Comment: Take a look at [this guide in the Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/router#router-links) it explains it pretty well

Comment: You should seriously check the docs before using SO as resource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following `<a></a>` tag

```
<a [routerLink]="['/registration/recovery']">RecoverPassword</a>
```

This will redirect you to the page